# MYSQL Setting a limit on the min/max return value of a math function?

Tags: mysql

I have been searching, but all I find are answers on how to Find, not SET the maximum return value of a function.

What I am looking for is simple..
If I want to update the entries in a column in proportion to themselves.. say..
SET `TheColumValue`=(`TheColumnValue`+(TheColumnValue*0.5));

Is there no MYSQL function to limit the resulting value?

SET `TheColumValue`=FUNCTIONNAME(`TheColumnValue`+(TheColumnValue*0.5), MAXIMUMVALUE);

I have written my own function to handle the need for now, but it seems to me such a simple, and obvious need that it would be part of the language.
Am I just not finding it in the Ref. manual or does such a function actually not exist in MYSQL?

Answer (score 4):

Of course there is.  It is called [`LEAST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least):

```
SET TheColumValue = LEAST(TheColumnValue+(TheColumnValue*0.5), MAXIMUMVALUE)
```

More succinctly written as:

```
SET TheColumValue = LEAST(TheColumnValue * 1.5, MAXIMUMVALUE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
I hate to come here to ask for help on things like this -when I know it is in the book somewhere and simply cannot find it.

In this case, I would have assumed LEAST to be a counter(in similar use) to MAX() rather than this.